# Print function result but two line with a None is printed

Tags: python

> Create a function named `same_name()` that has two parameters named
> `your_name` and `my_name`.
>
> If our names are identical, return `True`. Otherwise, return `False`.

My code:

```
def same_name(your_name, my_name):
  if your_name == my_name:
    print(True)
  else:
    print(False)
  
print(same_name("Colby", "Colby"))
print(same_name("Tina", "Amber"))
```

The output is:

```py
print(same_name("Colby", "Colby"))
# True
# None
print(same_name("Tina", "Amber"))
# False
# None
```

But the expected output is:

```py
print(same_name("Colby", "Colby"))
# True
print(same_name("Tina", "Amber"))
# False
```

Where `None` is coming from?

Comment: "Function problems in Python" What is your problem?

Comment: Use `return` - [recommended reading](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## return, not print

It's a common mistake to print instead of return. If a function need to return a value, `print` won't do it, it's just for the user, commonly used to debug. Since there is no return statement in your function, the function return None by default. In `print(same_name("Colby", "Colby"))`, you print the returned value of the function, which is `None`, so you print a second time (the first one is in the function) with a `None` value.

```py
  if your_name == my_name:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

**Usually, there is two types of exercises, those who ask you to create/code a function, and those who doesn't.**

### When you don't need a function:

Example with your exercise:

> Ask two names to the user. If the first name is equal to the second
> name, print `True`, if not, print `False`.

The expected code would be something like this:

```py
name_1 = input('name?')
name_2 = input('name?')
if name_1 == name_2:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

or the shorter alternative:

```py
name_1 = input('name?')
name_2 = input('name?')
print(name_1 == name_2)
```

### When you do need a function:

Example with your exercise:

> Create a function called `same_name` that takes two names. If the first name are equal
> to the second name, return `True`, if not, return `False`.

The expected code would be something like this:

```py
def same_name(name_1, name_2):
    if name_1 == name_2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

or the shorter alternative:

```py
def same_name(name_1, name_2):
    return name_1 == name_2
```

If you run the program with the function, you won't print anything, even if you call the function like `same_name("Colby", "Colby")`. It's because `return` doesn't print anything, it quit the function with a value. That's why they surrounded the function call with `print`, to print the returned value, see the result and make sure it match the expected behavior.

### Notes: The recommended practice is to return the condition result

The recommended practice is to return the condition result instead of branching with if:

```py
def same_name(your_name, my_name):
    return your_name == my_name
```